# How can I slow down my phone?

Tags: performance

I know it seems like a silly question, but here is the situation: I'm debugging an app and my users have reported a bug on slow devices that I can't see on my fast device.  Is there anything I can do to slow my device down so that I can see the bug for myself?

Comment: Have you tried using the emulator to create an AVD with similar specs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option - if you have root and a proper custom kernel you can use something like [SetCPU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mhuang.overclocking&hl=en) to underclock your processor. CyanogenMod also has this functionality built in since at least CM7, don't remember if it's in CM6. That can be found in `Settings->CyanogenMod Settings->Performance` IIRC. Without root access, I suppose you could try to run some kind of "expensive" process in an attempt to occupy CPU cycles, but its probably not the best of ideas or an accurate portrayal of a slower device.